# How to override a get method with a set method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a method, like this:

```
  public static ISalesPersonManager SalesPersons { get; }
```

But this is in a dll class. So I can't modify this class.

But I want to add a set method to this method.

So like this:

```
  public static ISalesPersonManager SalesPersons { get;set; }
```

But how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: you cannot override static member, you can shadow but it is normally not preferred as it can cause unexpected behaviors in program

Comment: oke. Thank you. nice. But what is then a solution? How to add a get method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to override a get only property to have a setter. Even though the concept of base class is only to describe what it's child "should do" and not what its child "shouldn't", that's how Microsoft has designed it.